# Angular select value and pass that value as a parameter in api

Tags: angular

I need help with my code. I am fetching the data from api (which is too large) in api their is restriction of showing only 500 array. but their is a parameter of company_id. I am fetching the data which only show 500 array. But i need when i select company_id it will pass the company_id in api and show that result in .html

this is home.html

```
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-12">
       <div class="content-header">Claims Status</div>
         <p class="content-sub-header">Claims Settled 23</p>
      </div>
    </div>
   <section id="extended">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12">
         <div class="card">
           <div class="card-header">
                  <div class="card-title-wrap bar-success">
              <h4 class="card-title">Claims</h4>
                  </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-block">

                                      <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                          <div class="form-group" >
                              <label for="">Search Name</label>

                                <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userFilter.member_name" placeholder="Search name" name="search">
                            </div>
                      </div>

                     <div class="col-md-3">
                          <div class="form-group" >
                              <label for="">Search Claim No</label>
                              <input type="search"
                                class="form-control" placeholder="Claim No" [(ngModel)]="userFilter.claim_no">
                            </div>
                      </div>


                      <div class="col-md-3">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="">Company</label>
                              <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userFilter.company_id" >
                                  <option value='' >All</option>

                                  <option value="999">Airlink Communication</option>
                                  <option value="637">Ascertia (Pvt) Ltd</option>
                                  <option value="1053">Frontier Works Organization</option>
                                 <option value="1174">Ebryx (pvt) Ltd</option>
                                  <option value="274">HY Enterprises (Pvt) Limited</option>
                                 <option value="459">Naimat Saleem trust NST (US GROUP)</option>
                                 <option value="659">Samad Rubber Works (Pvt) Ltd</option>
                                <option value="56">Sundry Clients</option>
                                <option value="620">TIMEXPERTS (PRIVATE) Limited</option>
                                <option value="39">US Apparel & Textile (Pvt) Limited</option>
                                <option value="40">US Denim Mills (Pvt) Limited</option>

                                </select>
                            </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-3">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Claim Status</label>
                            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userFilter.status">
                              <option value='' >All</option>

                              <option value="submitted">Submitted</option>
                              <option value="approved">Approved</option>
                              <option value="cancel">Objection Claim</option>
                              <option value="settled">Settled</option>
                             <option value="rejected">Rejected</option>


                            </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                  <table class="table table-responsive-md text-center">
                      <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th>STATUS</th>
                              <th>Name</th>
                              <th>Patient Name</th>
                              <th>Claimed Amount</th>
                              <th>Company</th>
                              <th>Submitted By</th>
                              <th>Claim No</th>
                              <!-- <th>Website URL</th> -->

                          </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody *ngIf="data">
                            <tr *ngFor="let x of data | filterBy: userFilter">



                                  <td>
                                    <span class="text-success" *ngIf="x.status == 'submitted'">Submitted</span>
                                    <span class="text-primary" *ngIf="x.status == 'settled'">Settled</span>
                                    <span class="text-warning" *ngIf="x.status == 'rejected'">Rejected</span>
                                    <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="x.status == 'Approved'">Approved</span>
                                    <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="x.status == 'ojection claim'">Objection claim</span>


                                </td>
                              <td>
                                <img [src]="x.userPhoto || 'https://mbtskoudsalg.com/images/user-image-png.png'" class="img-sm" alt="">
                                {{x.member_name}}
                              </td>
                              <td>{{x.patient_name}}</td>
                              <td>{{x.claimed_value}}</td>
                              <td>                                      



                                  <span  class="text-success" *ngIf="x.company_id == '999'" >Airlink Communication</span>
                                  <span class="text-success" *ngIf="x.company_id == '637'">Ascertia (Pvt) Ltd</span>
                                  <span *ngIf="x.company_id == '1053'" class="text-success">Frontier Works Organization</span>
                                 <span *ngIf="x.company_id == '1174'" class="text-success">Ebryx (pvt) Ltd</span>
                                  <span  *ngIf="x.company_id == '274'" class="text-success">HY Enterprises (Pvt) Limited</span>
                                 <span *ngIf="x.company_id == '459'" class="text-success">Naimat Saleem trust NST (US GROUP)</span>
                                 <span *ngIf="x.company_id == '659'" class="text-success">Samad Rubber Works (Pvt) Ltd</span>
                                <span *ngIf="x.company_id == '56'" class="text-success">Sundry Clients</span>
                                <span *ngIf="x.company_id == '620'" class="text-success">TIMEXPERTS (PRIVATE) Limited</span>
                                <span *ngIf="x.company_id == '39'" class="text-success">US Apparel & Textile (Pvt) Limited</span>
                                <span *ngIf="x.company_id == '40'" class="text-success">US Denim Mills (Pvt) Limited</span>


                               </td>
                               <td>{{x.claim_no}}</td>
                              <td>{{x.submitted_at || 'not-defined'}}

                              </td>

                          </tr>
                      </tbody>
                  </table>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

this is home.component.ts where i m fetching the data from api

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from 'app/services/api/api.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
 })
export class HomeComponent {

 clientData: Observable<any>;
 data: any  = []; 
 constructor(private api:ApiService, public httpClient: HttpClient) { 

 this.getClaims();

 }

 userFilter: any = { claim_no:'', member_name:'', status:'', company_id: 
  ''};

getClaims(){

  this.clientData = this.httpClient.get('xyz.com?').
  subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
  this.data = data.records;

    });

   }  

}
```

More Defining my question: Its succesfully show the data from api.
(not all data just 500 array because its set in api that only show 500 data but if i pass parameter of company_id so it will show that company_id from all data in api not from 500).
What i need to take the company id value from  and pass it as a parameter in api then show the result of that company_id .

Comment: Which attribute is used for passing company id to the API? Also, is it in the header or as params?

Comment: company_id : selected value;  and it is params

Comment: example : http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/insurance_IGItakaful/insurance-api/get_claims.php?company_id=659   you can also check this api in postman .

Comment: How are you submitting the form? are you using ngForm? If yes, please provide the form tag in the question.

Comment: no im not using form . i also attach the whole code of .html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your html try to use `(change)` method in `<select>` like this

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Company</label>
      <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userFilter.company_id" (change)="getClaims()">
        <option value='' >All</option>
        <option value="999">Airlink Communication</option>
        <option value="637">Ascertia (Pvt) Ltd</option>
        <option value="1053">Frontier Works Organization</option>
        <option value="1174">Ebryx (pvt) Ltd</option>
        <option value="274">HY Enterprises (Pvt) Limited</option>
        <option value="459">Naimat Saleem trust NST (US GROUP)</option>
        <option value="659">Samad Rubber Works (Pvt) Ltd</option>
        <option value="56">Sundry Clients</option>
        <option value="620">TIMEXPERTS (PRIVATE) Limited</option>
        <option value="39">US Apparel & Textile (Pvt) Limited</option>
        <option value="40">US Denim Mills (Pvt) Limited</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then in your `.ts` file, i am going to use if else in code but you can convert it in ternary condition.

```
getClaims(){
if(this.userFilter.company_id){
let url = 'http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/insurance_IGItakaful/insurance-api/get_claims.php?company_id='+this.userFilter.company_id;
}else{
let url = 'http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/insurance_IGItakaful/insurance-api/get_claims.php?';
}
  this.clientData = this.httpClient.get(url).
  subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
  this.data = data.records;

    });

   }
```